# Карточка товаров на Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Есть код-схема карточек товаров (codepen)](https://codepen.io/Gaxak/pen/qxGNva).

Как с текущей разметкой сверстать на флексах так,  чтобы полные ряды товаров (т.е. по 3 товара) вели себя как `space-between`, а не полный ряд как `space-around`? Если такое не возможно, какие могут быть пути решения?

з.ы. варианты с ручным добавление `margin` к товарам неполного ряда не подходят

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</article>
```

Comment: почему margin не подходят?

Comment: вариант с margin'ами не очень хорош, т.к. при добавлении новых товаров надо дописывать для них свойства. Интересует возможность настроить сетку так, чтобы неполный ряд товаров располагался по нужной логике автоматически

Answer (score 1):

как вариант с помощью JS. я только учусь, прошу строго не судить.
`

```
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
  let grid = document.querySelectorAll('article div'),
  div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  for (let i=0;i<3-grid.length%3;i++) {
    document.querySelector('article').appendChild(div);
  }
});
```

`

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, но хочется решение без JS